# Return to activity from which fragment activity started?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm starting a Fragment activity with 2 fragments from a menu item of an activity.
How can I return back to this activity by pressing the back key? With normal activities this happens by default but with fragment the first activity is destroyed.

Comment: When you move from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`, do you remove fragment A ? Also post your `java code` for this scenario here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an Intent when the method onBackPressed() is calling, for example :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), yourFirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
}
```

getActivity() is optimizing for Fragment.
Hope this help

Comment: I though about this too and tried it, but I get error on getActivity(): Cannot resolve method getActivity(). But I tried with: (this, FirstActivity.class) and works.